# Hashing images like CDs for Monster Rancher style randomizations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been kicking around an idea for creating a web based game where they can upload images in order to create random monsters/items. This I thought was most similar to how monster rancher randomized monsters from CDs. I was going to take a Sha512 approach. Assuming I could just take in the image, read the binary and then sha it. Taking each part of the SHA as bits and pieces (since it should always be the same length of string) as different attributes.

Besides images (which was the best thing I could think of) is there anything else I should consider hashing? Something small and ubiquitous? I loved CDs and DVDs but web based applications can't access those things and most computers won't even have them.

Comment: By definition you can hash anything you can get into binary. Usernames, IP addresses, URLs, whole websites, social media feeds, songs, videos, time stamps, geolocations, etc. So, I'm not sure what kind of answer to this question would be "correct and complete". Can you establish any specific criteria that the hashable thing needs to fulfill in order to serve your particular game's goals?

Comment: I actually kind of dig the idea of Geolocations. They are ubiquitous, they can be spoofed, but if laid over a map it could easily lead to the "Explore Here" kind of thing. I think you absolutely solved this for me. If you post that as an answer, i'd gladly accept it!

Comment: I'll defer that to someone who has the time to write an answer explaining the risks that arise if your hash function decides to place a high-value item in a places it would be inappropriate for players to go, like someone's private property, a military base, a graveyard, a hazardous river... and what mitigations you might take to deal with that.

Comment: Oh yeah. Definitely run into a lot of that with these new AR games. I'm thinking more of using something like OpenMaps and letting players "click" on the map to "send a search party" there. Saves all of the problems of having people potentially be put at risk and is a bit more COVID friendly currently.